# Converting MongoDB ObjectID to a valid id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch a document from MongoDB like this:

```
let document = await db.collection('administration').findOne({ _id: result.feedId });
```

And this is `result.feedId`:

```
{
     _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
     id: Uint8Array(12) [
     96, 129, 130, 179, 211,
     203, 136,  42, 149, 106,
     68,  49
     ]
}
```

However, while trying to do that I'm getting an error like this:

```
Error: object [{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"0":96,"1":129,"2":130,"3":179,"4":211,"5":203,"6":136,"7":42,"8":149,"9":106,"10":68,"11":49}}] is not a valid ObjectId
```

As far as I know, if `_id` is bson type then I don't need to convert it to ObjectId. However, I get such an error when I did not convert it.

When I try to convert it, I get an error like this:

```
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
let document = await db.collection('administration').findOne({ _id: ObjectID( result.feedId )});
```

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

How can I convert convert/fix that `result.feedId` to a valid id?

Edit:

I can't convert `result.feedId` object to string with `result.feedId.toString()`.

When I try to do that, I'm getting a result like this:

```
// console.log(result.feedId.toString());
[object Object]
//console.log(JSON.stringify(result.feedId.toString()));
"[object Object]"
```

Edit 2:

I don't have any idea why this has happened but `id` array in the `result.feedId` is what was I'm looking for. When I tried to convert that hex I got the `_id`

```
const id = Buffer.from(result.feedId.id).toString('hex');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the error:

```
Error: object [{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"0":96,"1":129,"2":130,"3":179,"4":211,"5":203,"6":136,"7":42,"8":149,"9":106,"10":68,"11":49}}] is not a valid ObjectId
```

saying that the issue is that `result.feedId` is actually an array containing the `ObjectID` you're interested in?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Yes there's an `id` key in the object but that's not the `_id` I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to convert that `id` and it's worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your result.feedId is an object but _id should not be object and instead it should be string as the error you posted suggests. Try changing what you pass as an _id.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I'm not sure how can I convert that object to a string. `ObjectId.toString()` is not working in my case. I edited my answer

Comment: Where are you getting that result.feedId from?

Comment: I also get it from the database. Then I put it into a lot of processing. but I'm not touching the `_id`